# How to Get the SUM Value from Grouped by Last value in a table result

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have this query table,

```
CREATE TABLE BASE_Purchase
(
PurchaseId BIGINT,
PurchaseDate DATE NOT NULL,
SupplierName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Amount MONEY NOT NULL,
Outstanding MONEY NULL
PRIMARY KEY(PurchaseId)
)
```

I have the following result set from the table,

[image]

Above image result query ↑

```
SELECT PurchaseId, PurchaseDate, SupplierName, Amount, Outstanding
FROM BASE_Purchase
ORDER BY SupplierName, PurchaseId
```

I need the above should be result as follow,
[image]

After retrieved the above result and i want to get the SUM of each outstanding

Comment: So, you want the row with the latest `PurchaseDate` for each `SupplierName` from your `Results`?  Your tags indicate both SQL2008 and SQL2014.  Does the solution have to run on both?

Comment: Yes, First Table i have entered all my purchase details supplier wise, outstanding amount in a row is for the particular row date of outstanding. i want to get the result supplier wise their Last outstanding amount order of purchase id (display on my second image)

Comment: How do you want to handle the situation where you have two rows for the same supplier and max `purchasedate`?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your images, something like this should run on SQL Server 2008.

(It's not completely tested because I didn't want to have to type all that data from your screenprints.)

```
;WITH _cte
AS (
    SELECT PurchaseId
        ,PurchaseDate
        ,SupplierName
        ,Amount
        ,Outstanding
    FROM BASE_Purchase
    )
SELECT PurchaseId
    ,PurchaseDate
    ,SupplierName
    ,Outstanding
FROM _cte c
WHERE PurchaseDate = (
        SELECT max(PurchaseDate)
        FROM _cte
        WHERE SupplierName = c.SupplierName
        )
```